# Filling a pandas dataframe with data from another dataframe based on certain conditions

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have a pandas data frame named "optns" with information about S&P500 options, with 3 columns: 'Date','Best Offer','Money Ticker'. I created a new data frame "price" that has 8 columns that represent different values for 'Money Ticker'. I want to fill this data frame with 'Best offer' values for the corresponding date. I wrote a code but its far from efficient and may even be wrong:

```
for j in range(0,price.shape[0]):
    for i in range(0,optns.shape[0]):
        if (price.loc[j,'Date']==optns.loc[i,'Date']) and (optns.loc[i,'Money Ticker']== 'Call OTM 10%'):
            price.loc[j,'Call OTM 10%']=optns.loc[i,'best_offer']
        if (price.loc[j,'Date']==optns.loc[i,'Date']) and (optns.loc[i,'Money Ticker']== 'Call OTM 7%'):
            price.loc[j,'Call OTM 7%']=optns.loc[i,'best_offer']
        if (price.loc[j,'Date']==optns.loc[i,'Date']) and (optns.loc[i,'Money Ticker']== 'Call OTM 5%'):
            price.loc[j,'Call OTM 5%']=optns.loc[i,'best_offer']
        if (price.loc[j,'Date']==optns.loc[i,'Date']) and (optns.loc[i,'Money Ticker']== 'Call ATM'):
            price.loc[j,'Call ATM']=optns.loc[i,'best_offer']
        if (price.loc[j,'Date']==optns.loc[i,'Date']) and (optns.loc[i,'Money Ticker']== 'Put ATM'):
            price.loc[j,'ATM']=optns.loc[i,'best_offer']
        if (price.loc[j,'Date']==optns.loc[i,'Date']) and (optns.loc[i,'Money Ticker']== 'Put OTM 5%'):
            price.loc[j,'Put OTM 5%']=optns.loc[i,'best_offer']
        if (price.loc[j,'Date']==optns.loc[i,'Date']) and (optns.loc[i,'Money Ticker']== 'Put OTM 7%'):
            price.loc[j,'Put OTM 7%']=optns.loc[i,'best_offer']
        if (price.loc[j,'Date']==optns.loc[i,'Date']) and (optns.loc[i,'Money Ticker']== 'Put OTM 10%'):
            price.loc[j,'Put OTM 10%']=optns.loc[i,'best_offer']
```

How can I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you looking for is [pd.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html).
I am not sure if i understood your dataframe fully but if i got it this should solve your problem:

```
pd.pivot_table(optns, columns="Money Ticker", values="Best Offer", index="Date")
```

You can check the linked documentation for more info.